# Flipped (Y-axis) Raster from point cloud

Tags: python, raster, gdal, resampling, point-cloud

I have been working on a project where I need to create rasters from irregularly spaced point clouds.  I am resampling my point clouds to a regular 0.25 cm grid using a nearest neighbor method [pyresample](http://pyresample.readthedocs.org/en/latest/swath.html#pyresample-kd-tree).  I am using the output array to make a raster using GDAL and my raster is inverted on the y-axis.  For a particular dataset I get the extents and apply a geotransfrom using the following parameters:

```
top_left_x(i.e., xMin)
top_left_y(i.e., yMax)
x_resolution
y_resolution
x_rotation
y_rotation
```

For a hypothetical dataset, let's say my geo transform parameters are:

```
top_left_x(i.e., xMin)=223280.0
top_left_y(i.e., yMax)=577877.75
x_resolution=0.25
y_resolution=-0.25
x_rotation=0
y_rotation=0
```

Using GDAL's `GTiff` driver I am successfully creating rasters by writing the output array `Result` to `rasterband(1)`.  The problem is the output raster us upside down w.r.t the y axis.  If I flip the array `result` using `numpy` like: `np.flipud(result)`, the raster is plotted in the correct position.  I am at a loss why I need to flip `result` and want to see if someone can help me understand why.

Comment: Perhaps because of this line `lats = np.fromfunction(lambda y, x: 75 - y, (50, 10))` the sign of the y_resolution is changed and you change it another time by giving it as negative.

Comment: If I switch `y_resolution` to a positive value, the raster will plot in the same reversed y order, with different extents (i.e., the nothing of the top_left_y becomes the nothing of the  `bottom_right_y` pixel)

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact rows are counted upwards in the negative-positive northing direction while geographical counts upwards in the positive-negative northing direction.